# Append one find query result to other mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two mongoose queries like this:

```
var doc1=model.find({name:"ABC"});
var doc2=model.find({name:"XYZ"});
```

I want to append the result of query 2 to query 1. I am doing like this:

```
doc1.append(doc2);
```

But above line gives error that `doc1.append()` is not a function. The obvious question is that if find returns an array of documents, then why `append` is not available on the result variable.

Can anyone help me to find something which will append the two query results one after the other?

Thank You!

Comment: When you say 'append the results', do you mean something like combining the two sets of results into a single set of results or are you attempting to merge actual documents together. Your text mostly suggests the former (and you could probably append `.toArray()` onto each of the first two lines which may then allow `.append()` to work afterwards), but the variable names somewhat suggest the latter. If it is the former you are looking to do, you might alternatively want to do something like use `$or` or `$unionWith` to just make one request to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.append()` will not work with [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods). Use [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead.

The solution should be:

```js
var doc1=model.find({name:"ABC"});
var doc2=model.find({name:"XYZ"});

var appened = doc1.concat(doc2);
```